# Book about a Roman and Gaul that cross swords

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a series where a Roman Soldier and a Gaul Soldier cross magic swords that send them through a rift to another dimension.

Comment: When did you come across this series? Was it new at the time? Do you remember any more details about it?

Comment: I know I read the series in the late 1990's, but don't think it was new then.  I remember when the two crossed swords a troop of Roman soldiers and the one Gaul went to the new land, the books are then about them in this new land.

Answer (score 14):

That sounds like [the Videssos cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Videssos_cycle) by Harry Turtledove.

> During an encounter with a Celtic force, a Roman legion is magically transported to another world when the two opposing leaders' swords touch. The Roman force and Celtic leader find themselves in an empire called Videssos. This empire hires them as a mercenary force to help defend their lands from an enemy nation, Yezd. It quickly becomes apparent to the leader of the legionaries, Marcus Aemilius Scaurus, that the Empire is rife with political intrigue. With steadfast loyalty to the Emperor and a certain bull-headedness, Marcus manages to safely navigate the particularly dangerous political landscape and advance the place of himself and his men.

Published in 1987.

Comment: @JohnOsburn: If you're certain that this is the right answer, you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so people know not to make other suggestions...